# Change all cell values in table column, already using 2D array for row and cell

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/1p770371j

The above demo shows a table where you can change data in each sell and the 2d array records which row and column cell the data change occurred. I have just added a column button to the colum header titles.

The idea is that the button will change all the column values to the same value. It opens up a dialog that has the 3 options. Once clicked all the options within that column changes accordingly.

This is the handle that returns each individual cell/row data upon change, which is fine.

```
  handleValue = (event, val, rowIdx, cellIdx) => {
    const newValue = [...this.state.value];
    newValue[rowIdx][cellIdx] = val;
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };
```

I have a new handle for the update all column:

```
  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

which just changes the select value at the minute, but this value will need to update all in that column, guessing it will need to look like the above handle something like this...

```
  handleChange = event => {
    const newAllValues = [...this.state.value];

    newAllValues = [event.target.value]

    this.setState({
      value: newAllValues
    });
  };
```

Any assistance in this would be great, will I need to introduce a 3rd array property for the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `handleChange` which column you intend to update as argument and update each row against that column name.

I also think (I could be wrong) you intend to keep the state of all "column wise" select values in state too. But currently you are keeping it against state.status. This way, selecting "Yes" in one column would change other columns select menu to "Yes", right?

So I changed the `status` to be an object:

```
state = {
  value: selected,
  status: {}
};
```

Now logic of updating `status` should be added to your `handleChange` function too. The idea is similar, update whichever column's select menu has been changed.

So the handler becomes:

```
// take `column` as parameter
// update each row's `column` value. i.e. row[column]
handleChange = column => event => {
    const newValue = this.state.value.map(row => ({
      ...row,
      [column]: event.target.value
    }));

    this.setState({
      // status is now object, save whichever column just been selected
      status: {
        ...this.state.status,
        [column]: event.target.value
      },
      // set value to newly calculated rows
      value: newValue
    });
};
```

I also made minor modifications in your render method to adapt to new shape of your state and new signature of `handleChange`. 
For exmaple:

```
<Select
  native
  value={this.state.status[mItem.value]} // i.e. status['Seniors']
  onChange={this.handleChange(mItem.value)} // sends 'Seniors' as argument
  input={<Input id="status-native-simple" />}
>
  //...
</Select>
```

Here is the forked sandbox:

[image: Edit Material demo]